# Pasar datos de un array PHP a javascript con "," para que interprete charts.js

Tags: javascript, php, array, json

Estoy generando un Dashboard con diferentes gráficos, en algunos con pasar 2 o tres variables de forma estándar `<?php echo ... ?>` ya es suficiente. El caso es que quiero pasar los datos de un array de los datos recogidos por mes del año y no soy capaz de que recoja la coma ",". Por otros lados me comentan de pasarlo a Json y lo he intentado pero no me sale nada.

```
  $contador_de_accidentes_mes = array(
    '01' => 0, '02' => 0, '03' => 0, '04' => 0,
    '05' => 0, '06' => 0, '07' => 0, '08' => 0,
    '09' => 0, '10' => 0, '11' => 0, '12' => 0
  );

  foreach ($accidentes_datos as $accidentes_dato) {
    $mesaccidente = date("m", strtotime($accidentes_dato['fecha_ace']));
    $anioaccidente = date("Y", strtotime($accidentes_dato['fecha_ace']));

    if ($anioaccidente == $anio && isset($contador_de_accidentes_mes[$mesaccidente])) {
      $contador_de_accidentes_mes[$mesaccidente]++;
    }
  }

  $my_json_string = json_encode($contador_de_accidentes_mes);

  // Imprimir los contadores de formaciones por mes
  foreach ($contador_de_accidentes_mes as $mes => $contador) {echo "$contador";}
  ?>
```

Esta es la parte del cálculo donde tengo el contador de registros por mes del año.

Ahora os paso como tengo la parte del script del *chart.js* donde quiero pasar todos los datos con una coma:

```
  /*
   *  CHART ACCIDENTES POR MES
   * -----------
   */
  var chartDom = document.getElementById('graficaaccidentes');
  var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
  var option;

  option = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      axisPointer: {
        type: 'shadow'
      }
    },
    grid: {
      left: '3%',
      right: '4%',
      bottom: '3%',
      containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'category',
      data: ['En', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
      axisTick: {
        alignWithLabel: true
      }
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      type: 'value'
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: '60%',
      data: JSON.parse("<?php echo $my_json_string ?>"),

    }]
  };

  option && myChart.setOption(option);
</script>
```

Comment: Prueba `data: "<?php echo $my_json_string?>"`

Comment: no, no funciona

Comment: Intenta compartir los errores/debugs que te están dando, sino es difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @EmiliVives, podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar: ¿exactamente que libreria estas usando para los gráficos? ¿que tipo de gráifo estas intentado crear? ¿podes poner el código js completo? Por otro lado, veo que tenes algunas preguntas con respuestas te recomiendo leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @RoyBogado, creo que lo correcto sería `data: JSON.parse("<?php echo $my_json_string?>")` o `data: <?php echo $my_json_string?>` (_esta última podría mostrar un error si usas un linter_)

Comment: @Marcos ya está haciendo un `json_encode()`... no hace falta el JSON.parse. Y al final tiene un string de json, que debe ponerlo entre comillas

Comment: @RoyBogado, hice [esta demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/48554) para que veas porque no hay que poner las comillas. PD: para usar JSON.parse, tendrían que ser comillas simples

Comment: @Marcos,  gracias a los dos. En este caso la grafica la he cogido de apache echart.js. He pasado codigo arriba. Mientras voy a coger otra grafica del dashboard que estoy haciendo que es de charts.js a ver si funciona.

Comment: Al fin!! efectivamente, algo de librerias se debia tratar en este caso, he seguido la opcion de <?php echo $my_json_string?> ya que ya estaba haciendo el JSON.parse en la parte del contador. Gracias a los dos.

Comment: @EmiliVives, recordá que podes responder a tu propia pregunta. Sería bueno que lo hagas ya que este problema se le puede presentar a alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

Al final consigo que funcione siguiendo a @Marcos poniendo en el script del grafico:

```
data: <?php echo my_json_string?>
```

Por otra via en el contador una vez finalizado realizo:

```
JSON.parse("<?php echo $my_json_string?>")
```

Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.